# Login with username and/or email

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm struggling with a problem for so many days already that I finally decided to ask for some help. 
I want to implement a login that either accepts a user's email or username in one input field. I've got the username-only login to work fine but I've tried to work in the email-login and wasn't successful at all.

My table fields in mysql are 'username' and 'email', would be cool if someone could offer me some help! Thank you very much!

Here's my code that I've tried:

```
public function find($user = null) {
    if($user) {
     $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'username';
     $data = $this->_db->get('users', array($field, '=', $user));

        if($data->count()) {
            $this->_data = $data->first();
            return true;
        }
    }
    else if($user) {
     $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'email';
     $data = $this->_db->get('users', array($field, '=', $user));

        if($data->count()) {
            $this->_data = $data->first();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function login($username = null, $useremail = null, $password = null, $remember = false) {

    if(!$username && !$password || !$useremail && !$password && $this->exists()) {
        Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);
    } else {
        $user = $this->find($username);
        $useremail = $this->find($email);
        if($user or $useremail) {
            if($this->data()->password === Hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt)) {
                Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);                   
                if($remember) {
                    $hash = Hash::unique();
                    $hashCheck = $this->_db->get('users_session', array('user_id', '=', $this->data()->id));
                    if(!$hashCheck->count()) {
                        $this->_db->insert('users_session', array(
                            'user_id' => $this->data()->id,
                            'hash' => $hash
                        ));
                    } else {
                        $hash = $hashCheck->first()->hash;
                    }   

                    Cookie::put($this->_cookieName, $hash, Config::get('remember/cookie_expiry'));
                }

                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: How about the code that you are trying to use for username and email? And what errors are you getting?

Comment: What exactly wasn't successful about your implementation?

Comment: @Christopher Bottoms What I've tried is: 
    `public function login($username = null, $useremail = null, $password = null, $remember = false) {
  
  if(!$username && !$password || !$useremail && !$password && $this->exists()) {
   Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);
  } else {
    $user = $this->find($username);
    $useremail = $this->find($email);
   if($user or $useremail) { ` and it's still checking if it's a username only :-/ means I get my error: "wrong username"

Comment: @Fab I don't think cheking input against numeric value and direct it to id field is a good idea. What if I want my username be 1 or 2, or 123456, etc?

Comment: @Fab Could you please edit your question to include that code? It doesn't format well in comments and it looks like it's truncated because you hit the character limit too. Thanks.

Comment: @xurshid29 numeric isn't allowed

Comment: @Christopher Bottoms I edited the initial code I posted above... That's the code I tried it with...and I doesn't work. I think I'm missing something in the find function but I've deleted that code part several times as I've tried

Comment: @Fab so, there are id,username,email.. fields in your table, you're fetching by id or username, but where is your condition by email in `find` method?

Comment: @xurshid29 Yes correct! I've tried to fetch email in the `find` method, but didn't get it to work. SEE MY EDITS IN THE CODE I POSTED

Comment: @Fab ok, I suggest to change `username` to 'email' in `find` method, just for testing purpose. And pass email value (which exists).. If it works, just remove ternary operator and use `else if` condition (may be some regex rules can be used to detect email value..)..

Comment: @Fab The second condition never works in your edited post..

Comment: @xurshid29 The replacement with `email` against `username` inside the `find` method works! But how can I combine them...

Comment: @Fab I posted some unoptimized code in my answer.. check them..

Answer (score 0):

You may use this query to fetch the `row_id` from your `users` table.

```
$sql = "select * from `users` where username = $input OR email = $input";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in you `find` method:

```
$field = null;

if (is_numeric($user)) {
    $field = 'id';
}
else if(is_string($user)) {
    if (filter_var($user, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $field = 'email';
    }
    else {
        $field = 'username';
    }
}

if (null == $field) {
    return false;
}

$data = $this->_db->get('users', array($field, '=', $user));

....
```

Comment: Tried it, no didn't work properly :-/ I'll take a break and try it again a little later. I'll let u know if I can get it to work. Thanks for your support though